# Material-UI FormControl InputLabel display problem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image: Look at the label]

In the picture, you can see that my label is behind the outline but I don't know why it is. I didn't give any kind of style I just gave a minWidth that's it but still, it's one kind of broken I mean the label is behind the line. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Container, Grid, FormControl,
  InputLabel, Select, MenuItem
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    minWidth: 180
  }
});

class Account extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      age: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (event) => this.setState({ age: event.target.value });

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { age } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
              <FormControl
                className={classes.formControl}
                variant="outlined"
                size="small">
                <InputLabel>Age</InputLabel>
                <Select value={age} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                  <MenuItem value="">
                    <em>None</em>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Account);
```

Comment: can you give me working sandbox will try to fix there

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-darkness-0ru12?file=/src/Account.js

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: the_label]

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import { Container, Grid, FormControl,
         InputLabel, Select, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    minWidth: 180
  }
});

class Account extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      age: '',
      labelWidth: 0
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.inputLabel = createRef();
  }

  handleChange = (event) => this.setState({ age: event.target.value });

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ labelWidth: this.inputLabel.current.offsetWidth });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { age, labelWidth } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
              <FormControl
                className={classes.formControl}
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
              >
                <InputLabel ref={this.inputLabel}>Age</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  value={age}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  labelWidth={labelWidth}
                >
                  <MenuItem value="">
                    <em>None</em>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Account);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Select" did not have enough space. To proof the theory I have added a **< br >** break to create some extra space. Now it displays the age above the Select Field. Please adjust the Margin Top.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response to my Tweet, your answer is also good but I think I got a better solution this time. If you want then you can check my answer also.